# reactxp .error in opening app in web

Tags: web, react-native, reactxp

I created an react-xp app by

> `create-xp-app MyProject`
>   and tried to run in chrome but then [image]

please help me solve ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have realized there is no actual soultion for this issue . and started an issue in [create-xp-app](https://github.com/react-native-training/create-xp-app/issues/23)  in github . hope its get solved soon .

Answer (score 0):

`create-xp-app` is not maintained and out of sync with reactnative/react js and other dependencies.

I suggest you start from a reactxp sample.